# Numerical solution of a transcendental equation as a function of three arguments

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to find a function of $P1$, $Pn$ and $n$ which approximates $\xi$, below. I will implement this approximation in a much simpler application which doesn't provide numeric equation solving.

$$n=\frac{(1-Pn)^{\frac{\xi }{\xi +1}}-1}{(1-P1)^{\frac{\xi }{\xi +1}}-1}$$

How would you go about this? I've gotten mired in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html). I gather that it's possible and there's many ways to do it, but I'm at a loss where to start.

In case it's useful, here are the assumptions:

```
0 < P1 < 1 && 0 < Pn < 1 && n ∈ Integers && n > 1 && ξ ∈ Reals && 
  ξ != -1 && ξ != 0
```

Comment: Normally for a numerical solution, you would use `NSolve` or `FindRoot`, which require numerical inputs for all variables, doing away with the need for assumptions.

Comment: @BillWatts: Thanks, but my problem statement is explicitly to estimate the solution while leaving the arguments undefined. Please help me restate my question to make that more clear.

Comment: I don't see how we can help unless you tell us how $P_n$ depends on $n$

Comment: @m_goldberg Pn does not depend on n; it's the user-specified probability that x (factored out, above) is greater than n. Perhaps I should have shown a simpler example unrelated to my application...

Comment: "I will implement this approximation in a much simpler application which doesn't provide numeric equation solving."  Does this simpler application (Excel maybe?) provide some programming ability?  With an equation that gets you a good starting value, a Newton-Raphson algorithm could be programmed that would be quick and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your side question, the expression

```
$Assumptions = 
  {(x_ 1 | x_N | ξ) ∈ Reals, x_ 1 > 0, x_N > 0, ξ != 0, n ∈ Integers, n > 1}
```

has several errors.

1. The symbol `N` is a symbol reseved for the built-in function that forces numerical evaluation. Use `n` instead.
2. Consider

   ```
   x_1 | x_n // FullForm
   ```

   > ```
   > Alternatives[Pattern[x, Blank[]], Pattern[x, Blank[n]]]
   > ```

   You don't want `Pattern` and `Blank`, which are pattern matching functions. You want subscripting or indexing. Use `Subscript[x, 1]` and `Subscript[x, n]` or `x[1]` and `x[n]`.
3. Assumptions should be given in conjunctive form not as lists. That is,

   ```
   ξ != 0 && n ∈ Integers && n > 1
   ```

   not

   ```
   {ξ != 0, n ∈ Integers, n > 1}}
   ```
4. A relation such as `x > 0` implies that `x` is real, so for such variable you need not write `x ∈ Reals`.

Putting all the above together leads me to suggest you write your assumptions as

```
Subscript[x, 1] > 0 && Subscript[x, n] > 0 && ξ ∈ Reals && ξ != 0 && n ∈ Integers && n > 1
```

or

```
x[1] > 0 && x[n] > 0 && ξ ∈ Reals && ξ != 0 && n ∈ Integers && n > 1
```

#### Update

The following discussion is in response to further information supplied by the OP.

As I understand the problem on the basis of the new information, you want to find a function `u[a, b, n]` that satisfies

```
 n == ((1 - a)^(u/(1 + u)) - 1)/((1 - b)^(u/(1 + u)) - 1) && n ∈ Integers
```

But what about `a` and `b`? Are they constrained to the reals? Further, do you require `u` to be a real-valued function? These are difficult constraints to meet. I am pessimistic about finding any kind of solution under such constraints.

On the other hand, if `a` and `b` can be complex numbers and `u` can be complex valued, Mathematica can find numerical instances that satisfy your equation for certain integer values of `n`. But even under these relaxed constraints, I very much doubt that Mathematica can not write a symbolic expression that will represent `u`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my assumptions and Mathematica was able to simplify more than before.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but it looks like you are trying to solve a transcendental equation algebraically.  While MMa can undoubtedly solve more of those than I can, most of them it cannot.  A numerical method is generally required.  If you want a function that leaves n and the P's temporarily unevaluated, you could do something like this:

```
fn[n_, Pn_, P1_, atry_] := FindRoot[n - ((1 - Pn)^a - 1)/((1 - P1)^a - 1), {a, atry}][[1,2]]
```

where I changed the exponents to `a` in your equation.

with that you could do something like

```
a = fn[2, 0.5, 0.3, .1]
\[Xi] = -(a/(a - 1))

-0.168292
-0.14405
```

or if you want a range over n

```
 a = Table[fn[n, 0.9, 0.5, 0.01], {n, 2, 20}]
\[Xi] = -(a/(a - 1))

{0.777116,0.130946,-0.218891,-0.456588,-0.635699,-0.778973,-0.898135,-1.,-1.08887,-1.16763,-1.23832,-1.30239,-1.36098,-1.41492,-1.46489,-1.51142,-1.55495,-1.59584,-1.63439}

{3.48663,0.150677,-0.179582,-0.313464,-0.388641,-0.437878,-0.473167,-0.5,-0.521273,-0.538668,-0.553236,-0.565669,-0.576447,-0.585907,-0.594302,-0.601819,-0.608603,-0.614769,-0.620405}
```

You need to be careful with FindRoot, though, because it will give an answer even if it never converges, but it generally complains when that happens, so take those complaints seriously.  You can see from plots that for some combinations of `P1` and `Pn`, there are no roots for any `n`.

No assumptions necessary, although you can put restrictions on the arguments to your function.